# Making complex SQL query using Eloquent, need assistance

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I am working with an api call where you are supposed to search for a 'survey' and sum up the different answers (located in other tabels). I am fairly new to eloquent and this is a little to complicated for me so I need some help.

There is 4 different tables with data, Survey, SurveyAnswerSets, Survey_X, Survey_XY.

What I want to do is search for surveys using a title, startDate and endDate. From the fetched surveys I need to fetch additional information from the 3 other tabels. I think I am supposed to use eager loading.

This is the datafields I am supposed to fetch:

```
"surveyId": Survey.surveyId
"title": Survey.title
"startDate": Survey.startDate
"endDate": Survey.endDate
"targetReplies": Survey.targetReplies
"repliesExposed": Number of rows in SurveyAnswerSets where surveyId = surveyId and isRefGroup = 0 and isComplete = 1
"repliesControl": Number of rows in from SurveyAnswerSets where surveyId = surveyId and isRefGroup = 1 and isComplete = 1
"repliesTotal": Number of rows in from SurveyAnswerSets where surveyId = surveyId and isComplete = 1
"useRefGroup": Survey.useRefGroup
"orderId": Survey.orderId
"surveyXIds": Survey_X where surveyId = surveyId
"originalXYIds": Survey_XY where surveyId = surveyId
```

The easy part of selecting the correct surveys I have done:

```
$columns = array('surveyId', 'title', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'isTemplate');

$surveys = Survey::notemplate()
            ->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$name%")
            ->where('startDate', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
            ->where('endDate', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
            ->select($columns)
            ->get();
```

but this leaves the tricky parts where I need help or advice how to start.

Comment: If you want to get your results in one trip to the database I'd suggest to use  raw SQL query instead of trying to express it with Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

Eager loading is only an optimization (to prevent to many SQL queries).

You don't need to write more queries: just use the objects appropriate methods.

```
foreach($surveys as $survey){
  $repliesExposed = $survey->answers()->where(...)->count();
}
```

This supposes that you correctly configured the [relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: So assume I want to filter the answers, count the numbers of rows and assign that to a column (like repliesExposed) for each surveyId I filter out in my query without making a new db call for each surveyId. How can I do that?

Comment: I think that you should first try to make your code do what you need (even if it requires a lot a db calls) and then try to reduce the number of queries if it appears to be problematic.